# Csv Calculation using java

Tags: java, math, data-structures, csv

Thanks for reading my question. I have a CSV file, I read it and store it in a variable. 
Now i just want to PLUS all the column to see its sum. 
For example

```
3,34
12,673
23,8543


SUM
-------------
965,12658
```

Columns and rows can be N limit. Looks easy but don't know, its taking my all time. 
Please do let me know which data structure should I use? Or if you can tell me some
steps to solve this problem.
Thanks !

Comment: please see above values, i don't know what happened. But in example csv has 2 columns

Comment: Can you show the code that you have tried so far? We may be able to point out the areas that are causing you errors.

Comment: LinkedList<int> is an overkill here. You don't need to care for number of rows - only number of columns is important.

Comment: True ... I guess I am still drunk from last night.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used a 2-dimensional array. 1st represent column and 2nd represent rows.
I get a number of columns to declare dynamic 1st array then used a loop to store values and sum them.

Answer (score 3):

First of all I recommend using this library to read the CSV: http://opencsv.sourceforge.net/

Using this library you could write something like this:

```
CSVReader reader = new CSVReader(new FileReader("yourfile.csv"));
String [] firstLine = reader.readNext();
long sum;
for (String columnValue : firstLine) {
    try {
        sum += Long.parseLong(columnValue);
    } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
}
System.out.println(sum);
```

This example just reads the first line, but you could write a while-loop to keep parsing lines until the end of the file.

Comment: Sorry, I copied the wrong URL. I changed it to the correct one. Open CSV is the one you need.

Comment: thanks, It helped me to get the idea. I don't use opencsv when i can write my own program :)

Answer (score 2):

Since this is probably homework I won't give source code. You just need to read the lines and parse them using String.split. Convert them to integers using Integer.parseInt. Watch out for exceptions. If you have N columns you need to have N variables to hold the result. Update the variables after every read.

Comment: LOL, It is not an assignment. Also I did not ask for source code. I said if you can give me some hints. 
I am sorry but I couldn't understand your solution.
I can read csv. I can split them i can store all values in variable. But declaring N variable for columns at runtime is not a practical solution. Yeah may be in school you can do this just to pass exam ;)